# Logic to build 8x1 Mux Using Vivado HLS (Xilinx)

Tags: c++, xilinx, multiplexing, vivado-hls

I want to create 8x1 MUX IP BLOCK through HLS. MUX block should be 8 inputs and single output.
Eight input streams :Each input stream data width : 32 bit and output should be single output stream of 32 bit. I tried with below code but in simulation output is not. I am missing some logic behind this implementation. Can anyone guide me.

```
// MUX CODE 
    void 8x1_MUX(hls::stream<idata> &datain1,hls::stream<idata> &datain2,hls::stream<idata> &datain3,hls::stream<idata> &datain4,hls::stream<idata> &datain5,hls::stream<idata> &datain6,hls::stream<idata> &datain7,hls::stream<idata> &datain8,hls::stream<odata> &dataout,hls::stream<isel> sel)
    {
        isel select;
        select=sel.read();
          idata in1;
          idata in2;
          idata in3;
          idata in4;
          idata in5;
          idata in6;
          idata in7;
          idata in8;      
        
 switch(select)
        {
    
        case 1:
            //idata in1;
    
            if(!datain1.empty())
            {
                    in1=datain1.read();
                    dataout.write(in1);
            }
    
           break;
    
        case 2:
              // idata in2;
               if(!datain2.empty())
               {
                   in2=datain2.read();
                   dataout.write(in2);
               }  
            break;
    
        case 3:
                //idata in3;
                if(!datain3.empty())
                {
                    in3=datain3.read();
                    dataout.write(in3);
                }
                break;
    
        case 4:
                //idata in4;
                if(!datain4.empty())
                {
                    in4=datain4.read();
                    dataout.write(in4);
                }
    
                break;
    
        case 5:
                //idata in5;
                if(!datain5.empty())
                {
                    in5=datain5.read();
                    dataout.write(in5);
    
                }
                break;
    
        case 6:
               // idata in6;
                if(!datain6.empty())
                {
                    in6=datain6.read();
                    dataout.write(in6);
                }
                break;
    
        case 7:
               // idata in7;
                if(!datain7.empty())
                {
                    in7=datain7.read();
                    dataout.write(in7);
                }
                break;
    
        case 8:
               // idata in8;
                if(!datain8.empty())
                {
                    in8=datain8.read();
                    dataout.write(in8);
    
                }
            break;
    
        default:
                 //cout<<"invalid stream"<<endl;
                 break;
        }
  
    }
```

Comment: It would be best if you could post a test or a wave diagram showing the problem. However, it seems like your code could read sel and not output anything (if the appropriate datain stream is empty).

Comment: I'm shocked by the fact a 8to1 mux would result in so many lines of code using hls. But I should clarify I use traditional verilog only, and I don't have a general feeling on how rtl vs hls nowadays.

Comment: 8 Data generator block`s whereas each block output (Axi Stream) is 32 Bits and connected to each FIFO (totally 8 FIFO`s).  Each FIFO output is connected to 8x1 MUX. MUX should select one of the input of FIFO`s among 8 FIFO`s at that instance. I don`t know how to use select line to select input of FIFO`s. Whether the logic code which i wrote is right ?

Answer (score 0):

A possible, short, workaround, resulting in roughtly 2 cycles execution, would look something like this:

```
void 8x1_MUX(hls::stream<idata> datain[8], hls::stream<odata> &dataout, hls::stream<isel> &sel) {
#pragma HLS PIPELINE
  isel select = sel.read();
  idata packet;
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    if (i == select - 1) {
      if (datain[i].read_nb(packet)) {
        dataout.write(odata(packet));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Bear in mind that the `empty()` and `full()` methods are *not* synthesizeable (that's way I'm using the read non-blocking `read_nb()` method, as suggested in the HLS [guide](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2020_1/ug902-vivado-high-level-synthesis.pdf)).

Also, there's no check on your select `sel` FIFO port, so the IP might get stuck waiting for reading the selection packet.

Alternatevely, you can still use the switch-case structure like so:

```
void 8x1_MUX(hls::stream<idata> &datain1, hls::stream<idata> &datain2,
    hls::stream<idata> &datain3, hls::stream<idata> &datain4,
    hls::stream<idata> &datain5, hls::stream<idata> &datain6,
    hls::stream<idata> &datain7, hls::stream<idata> &datain8,
    hls::stream<odata> &dataout, hls::stream<isel> &sel) {
#pragma HLS PIPELINE
  isel select = sel.read();
  idata packet;
  switch(select) {
    case 1:
      if (datain1.read_nb(packet)) {
        dataout.write(odata(packet));
      }
      break;
    case 2:
      if (datain2.read_nb(packet)) {
        dataout.write(odata(packet));
      }
      break;
    case 3:
      if (datain3.read_nb(packet)) {
        dataout.write(odata(packet));
      }
      break;
    case 4:
      if (datain4.read_nb(packet)) {
        dataout.write(odata(packet));
      }
      break;
    case 5:
      if (datain5.read_nb(packet)) {
        dataout.write(odata(packet));
      }
      break;
    case 6:
      if (datain6.read_nb(packet)) {
        dataout.write(odata(packet));
      }
      break;
    case 7:
      if (datain7.read_nb(packet)) {
        dataout.write(odata(packet));
      }
      break;
    case 8:
      if (datain8.read_nb(packet)) {
        dataout.write(odata(packet));
      }
      break;
  }
}
```